# RavenDB and consistency

Tags: ravendb, eventual-consistency

I'm new to RavenDB and have spent some time reading up on the details. I'm a bit confused on how the handle the eventual consistency issue.

Let's assume a user of a web page is in the process of creating something. For example a new "case". (i.e. first a POST request is sent and a new document is created in RavenDB). Once created the user get routed back to the overview of cases (i.e. a GET request fetches all cases by querying raven for all case documents). Now from what I can tell there is no way I can make sure the case document that was just created will be included in this query since the index may be stale?

For other users, they are unlikely to care if the case appears at once since they are most likely unaware it was created in the first place so that is fine. But the user that actually created the case is very likely to be very confused if it is missing from the overview of cases. In other words, this is an issue that must be addressed.

How?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `WaitForReplicationAfterSaveChanges` for this, see: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/http/server/scaling-out/replication/write-assurance

Comment: Ah ok, great! I guess will happen more or less instantly under normal circumstances? It would be weird for the user to have to wait for several seconds before the save is "completed."

Comment: Does `WaitForReplicationAfterSaveChanges` also wait for affected indexes to be updated or only ensure that the document has been replicated to additional nodes?

Comment: You can also specify `WaitForIndexesAfterSaveChanges`

Answer (score 0):

I usually did something like this:

```
public IQueryable<Foo> GetAllFoos(bool waitForUpdatedIndex = false)
{
    IRavenQueryable<Foo> ret = _documentSession.Query<Foo>();

    if (waitForUpdatedIndex)
        ret.Customize(q => q.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow());

    return ret;
}
```

And then I would pass `true` for `waitForUpdatedIndex` if the user has previously added a new item.

Comment: Right, I understand your idea. Not sure it will work for me though. That requires some kind of contextual information being sent back to the web client in case the next request is handled by another web server. On the same server it might work if I cache this information but still a bit awkward. I guess it's more suitable for typical desktop apps where the context is held in memory and not isolated for each request.

Comment: You might have to combine it with Ayende's suggestion above if you have more than one RavenDB node but it should still work. Something like:

`public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "...")] ViewModel viewModel){if (ModelState.IsValid) {_docSession.SaveChanges(viewModel);return RedirectToAction("Index", new {waitForUpdatedIndex = true});}return View(viewModel);}`

Comment: Yeah I get it. Im not using MVC though (angularjs). While still possible, I don't really consider that information appropriate for a round trip to the web. I mean in theory the user should be able to quickly navigate to the overview in another web browser and still see the new case.